# Link error: "Cannot find -ltinfo" on Ubuntu 12.04 on a 32-bit arm processor

Tags: c++, ubuntu, arm, static-libraries, ubuntu-12.04

I get the following link error when I'm compiling a small function using ncurses for an Ubuntu 12.04 running on arm. The error is

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo
```

A lot of hints are floating around on what to install, but I can't seem to find any packages that does the trick for my arm box.

I have done

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

And this does not contain the tinfo library. Other suggestions usually result in the library is "not available but referred by another package" or "has no installation candidate".

All help is appreciated

/Henrik

Comment: Several sources suggest to just create libtinfo as a symlink to libncurses, did you try that already?  Eg see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142384

Comment: for what it's worth, you can try this : sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev

Comment: Could you provide with sample source code and exact compilation string?

Comment: The symlink worked, thanks! I also tried the libtinfo-dev, which worked nicely, I must have missed that simple one. For all of your answers I thank you!

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned by lucasg

```
sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev
```

solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

When you cross compile the nurses library, configure this option --with-termlib. It shall install libtinfo into your target location.