# What to do with error: cannot find ltinfo

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I compile a file which uses ncurses and I get an error. Cannot find -ltinfo. I installed what was recommended in this topic: [Link error: "Cannot find -ltinfo" on Ubuntu 12.04 on a 32-bit arm processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137879/link-error-cannot-find-ltinfo-on-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-32-bit-arm-processor)
and I still get this error

Comment: Where did you install it? You need to provide the path to the library if it is at some custom location.

Comment: @user3389943 how to do it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev` ....... On-line search : libtinfo.so  https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libtinfo.so ...... Or use `sudo apt-file search libtinfo.so`

Comment: You can put the library path as part of the build command using the -L switch